# Kubernetes's nginx-ingress routing doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I get **connection refused** when I try to curl to my WordPress, which I used K8s Ingress to access: this is my command & it's response:

```
curl http://behniafarahbod.ir/wordpress
curl: (7) Failed to connect to behniafarahbod.ir port 80 after 3 ms: Connection refused
```

This is my wordpress ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.wordpress.access.domain }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ .Values.wordpress.access.endpoint }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: wordpress-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Also this is my wordpress-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-service
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
```

**What's the problem here?**

(By the way, I installed nginx-ingress by thus command:

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

I don't know, if it is installed completely)

---

These might help you:

***Command***:

```
kubectl get ingress -n devops-test
```

***Result***:

```
NAME                 CLASS    HOSTS               ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
phpmyadmin-ingress   <none>   behniafarahbod.ir             80      175m
wordpress-ingress    <none>   behniafarahbod.ir             80      175m
```

Comment: Can you add the output of kubectl get ingress -n <namespace where ingress is deployed>

Comment: @Raghu Oh yes. I added it to the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: Where is this k8s cluster, on prem, cloud? If cloud in which one?

Comment: how do you get traffic to your ingress controller?

Comment: also note that you didnt add a class to your ingressses, so nginx will not operate on them. Still you should receive a 404, in that case.

Comment: @Hackerman This is a single-node cluster, deployed on my own server; not cloud.

Comment: @TheFool I just deployed this k8s cluster on the VM, and nothing else ( no outside-nginx or something like that). Also, I'm using Cloudflare DNS service, which is working fine.
Also, Can you help me how to add class to the ingresses? I'm new in k8s.

Comment: Do you a DNS in place to redirect your domain to your cluster public ip? If not and this is for testing, if you are on windows you can ad an entry to the windows host file to do that redirection.

Comment: for the ingress class https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class. For the actual problem, check on the status of your ingress controller service. It should show as pending because the default setting is set to `Loadbalancer`, which wants to provision an external lb with your cloud provider.

Comment: you need to change some values of that ingress-nginx helm release, to use something like `NodePort`.

Comment: here these docs should cover your case https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/